# How to reference a UI Element in a ResourceDictionary (Windows Store Apps)?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

The following works as expected:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Button x:Key="MyButton">Hello</Button>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyButton"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This does not:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Button x:Key="MyButton">Hello</Button>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyButton"/>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

(To reproduce, create a new Blank App in VS 2012 or VS 2013 RC and replace the content of MainPage.xaml with the above.)

I'm getting an unhandled exception with UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.Message = "Element is already the child of another element."

What am I doing wrong? Is this supposed to work?

Although it's not apparent here, I think I have a good reason to put some of my UI elements into a resource dictionary. I'm aware that each UI element can only ever appear in exactly one place, but even though this is the case in the second example, the error message claims otherwise.

Comment: Why are you not using [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709909.aspx)?

Comment: @Xyroid: I don't understand your suggestion. The requirement I have is that certain controls must reside in the resource dictionary. Exactly why I need this is a long story. I'm curious why it works for example 1 but doesn't for example 2.

Comment: I think he's asking why you don't just put your `Button` in as a `Style` template into your Resource Dictionary and then reference the style like `<Button Content="Hello" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}"/>` which would be a question I'd ask also.

Comment: @Chris W: It's a long story, but in a nutshell I need to refer to the button instance from multiple places and the usual ElementName approach doesn't work in my situation. So I thought I try to put it into resources.

Comment: So you want to use the exact same button instance over and over? Or you're just trying to use the same type of button over an over? If it's the latter than the resource dictionary would be the way to go. If it's the first though, then you'd probably want to just make it into a usercontrol instead.